# adding values to arrays of defined size in for loop

Tags: c, arrays

I have defined 6 arrays, and each array can contain 10 values:

```
static s16 arr_A[10];
static s16 arr_B[10];
static s16 arr_C[10];
static s16 arr_D[10];
static s16 arr_E[10];
static s16 arr_F[10];
```

Now I have an existing function which gives me values of interest:

```
FunctionContainsValuesOfInterest(&adc_values[0]);

myValues = adc_values[GROUP_A];
myValues = adc_values[GROUP_B];
myValues = adc_values[GROUP_C];
myValues = adc_values[GROUP_D];
myValues = adc_values[GROUP_E];
myValues = adc_values[GROUP_F];
```

At each call of FunctionContainsValuesOfInterest() I get new values. 
Now I would like to create a loop where I fill for example the 
    array arr_A[] wih 10 values of adc_values[GROUP_A], 
    arr_B[] with 10 values of adc_values[GROUP_B].

What is here the best and most efective procedure?

Comment: Types are missing, so cannot suggest anything.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the type of `adc_values` element is the same as that of `arr_X`s, i.e. `s16`, you can use [`memcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy) function to copy whole or a portion of `adc_values`:

```
memcpy(arr_A, &adc_values[GROUP_A], sizeof(arr_A));
```

The assumption above is that `adc_values[GROUP_A]` is that ten consecutive items at `adc_values[GROUP_A+i]` for `i` between 0 and 9, inclusive, are the values that need to be copied into `arr_A`.